# I need help getting data from two different sensors in C programming

Tags: c, embedded, freertos, task-queue

**So I basically have a temperature sensor and a photoresistor and I am trying to figure out how to separate the values that I am getting. This is what I have done so far:**

```
#define type_temp 0 

#define type_photo 1

typedef struct AMESSAGE{
    
    char        type;
    uint8_t     adc;

} AMESSAGE;
```

I tried to define two different types of data and assign that to each ADC in my project. Then I tried to call these two different types in my project and it did not work. I am wondering what I am doing wrong. My best guess is that I am creating the structure incorrectly.

```
void MyTask1(void *pvParameters)
{
    
    AMESSAGE    xMessage;
    uint8_t     adc;
    uint8_t     adc1;
    int16_t     vin;
    int16_t     vin1;
    char        str[80];
    
    ADC_StartConvert();
    ADC1_StartConvert();
    
    while(1){
        if (ADC_IsEndConversion(ADC_RETURN_STATUS)){ //ADC_WAIT_FOR_RESULT) ){
            adc = ADC_GetResult8();
            vin = ADC_CountsTo_mVolts(adc);   
            xMessage.adc = adc;            
         
        
        while ( xQueueSendToBack(xQueue, &xMessage.adc, pdMS_TO_TICKS(10)) != pdPASS){};
     
        } 
        vTaskDelay( pdMS_TO_TICKS(20)); // Delay for 20ms  
        
        
    if (ADC1_IsEndConversion(ADC1_RETURN_STATUS)){ //ADC_WAIT_FOR_RESULT) ){
        adc1 = ADC1_GetResult8();
        vin1 = ADC1_CountsTo_mVolts(adc1);   
        xMessage.adc = adc1;            
        
        
        while ( xQueueSendToBack(xQueue, &xMessage.adc, pdMS_TO_TICKS(10)) != pdPASS){};
     
        } 
        vTaskDelay( pdMS_TO_TICKS(20)); // Delay for 20ms  
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting data from just one of the sensors? Get that working, do the same for the other sensor by itself, then try to combine them somehow.

Comment: Hi, yes I have both of the sensors working individually, I am just confused on how to separate the data, also thank you so much for the response.

Comment: You’ll have to make the messages different, for example by setting aMessage.type to something different for each sensor, I’d assume that’s what `type_temp` and `type_photo` are for. FYI a common convention is to make constants like these all capitals, and to use an enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

You already have `type` field in the `AMESSAGE` sturcture. After conversion set it to the desired value - type_temp or type_photo (I assume that first `if` correctly receives data from one sensor, second - from another). Then send whole `xMessage` to the queue, not just ADC result

```
xQueueSendToBack(xQueue, &xMessage, pdMS_TO_TICKS(10));
```

Queue should be created with `sizeof(AMESSAGE)` item size.